# How do i transfer my postgresql database table to heroku using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, heroku

So I am a student with **no experience** in deploying a website. My database is connected, the problem is heroku doesn't know my tables. Every time I fetch data from heroku database, it's logging this error.

```
error: relation "texts" does not exist"
```

What do I have to do to transfer my tables to the heroku postgres ? I've been searching but to no avail. it's only giving me a headache. I've read using **dump** is one of the solutions, but I really don't know what it is.

Thanks for your time, please help me.

Comment: Are you using database migrations?

Comment: Forget a moment that you are deploying a website and concentrate on the database. Do you have the DDL of your database? Is it stored in a development database, on a filesystem or in a version control system?

Comment: No, im not using database migrations.. Is it have to do it that way ?

Comment: Georges Martin. Thanks for the reply. But i'm a newb, and i dont know where it is. I use postgres and pgAdmin 4 to do my database. So i think its on filesystem

Comment: When in pgAdmin, do you have different server connections? One to Heroku, one to a local database, perhaps? If so, where do you see the structure of your database?